# Plot an integral function for various values of the parameter

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

How can I plot the function

`F[x_,a_]:=Integrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1-2a), {z, -Infinity, -1}] + Integrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1-2a), {z, 1, Infinity}]`

for x in  (-1,1) and a in (0,1)?
I have been using Wolfram Cloud to do
`Plot[F[x,1], {x,-1,1}]`,
but I get that the computational time is exceeded
So my questions are:

- What does the plot look like? Is this an error or just a long computation?
- If I wrote `Plot[F[x,a], {x,-1,1}, {a,0,1}]`
  would it work to plot in the same picture the function F[x] for the various values of a? What if I just want to plot some values of a, for example a = 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1?

Answer (score 3):

Using some [assumptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) and an [immediate assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) gives an analytic integral, which is easy to plot:

```
F[x_, a_] = Assuming[-1 <= x <= 1 && a > 0,
  Integrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1 - 2 a), {z, -Infinity, -1}] + 
  Integrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1 - 2 a), {z, 1, Infinity}]]

(*    (1 - x)^(-2 a)/(2 a) + (1 + x)^(-2 a)/(2 a)    *)
```

The plot looks exactly like the one of [@Andreas' answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/244720/26598).

Comment: Thanks! Can i ask you too if it's possible to plot it in 1-d, with lines of different colors to represent the various values of a?

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[F[x, a], {a, {1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1}}], {x, -1, 1}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do numerical integration and a 3D plot like:

```
Plot3D[NIntegrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1 - 2 a), {z, -Infinity, -1}] + 
NIntegrate[Abs[x - z]^(-1 - 2 a), {z, 1, Infinity}], {x, -1, 1},    {a,0,1}]
```

[image]

a 1-d plot could look like

```
Plot[Evaluate[
 Table[((1 - x)^(-2*a) + (1 + x)^(-2*a))/(2*a), {a, 0.1, 1, 0.2}]], 
{x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I still get the output on the computational time exceeded though. Could you please add a plot to your answer?

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to plot it in 1-d, with lines of different colors to represent the various values of a?

Comment: with @Roman s result `Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[((1 - x)^(-2*a) + (1 + x)^(-2*a))/(2*a), {a, 0.1, 1, 0.2}]], 
   {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a picture of this too?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a big help. Is it possible to also have a legend of which colors correspond to which values of a?

Comment: you can add a legend with `Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[((1 - x)^(-2*a) + (1 + x)^(-2*a))/(2*a), {a, 0.1, 1, 
    0.2}]], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> Table[a, {a, 0.1, 1, 0.2}]]`